# Make the compiler generate an empty default function for an std::function

Tags: c++

In this code, I'd like `...` to be a non-verbose way of saying "empty function with the matching arguments":

```
std::function<void(int foo, float bar)> somefunc  = ...;
```

I want it to generate code corresponding to this but without repeating the argument types:

```
std::function<void(int foo, float bar)> somefunc  = [](int, float) {};
```

## Background

I can declare and initialize an `std::function` this way:

```
std::function<void(int foo, float bar)> somefunc;
```

Then I can call it like this:

```
if(somefunc) {
    somefunc(42, 4711.0f);
}
```

But the if statement bloats the code (and I'm not that fond of null pointers), so I can define the function with a default empty implementation:

```
std::function<void(int foo, float bar)> somefunc  = [](int, float) {};
```

and then the call will be simply:

```
somefunc(42, 4711.0f);
```

But it gets a little repetitive to repeat the arguments like this, so I'd like something that generates that empty implementation instead.

Comment: 'Null object' design pattern (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/null-object-design-pattern/)

Comment: You could create an `optional_function` wrapping `std::optional<std::function<...>>`. If those empty functions are common, this saves time.

Comment: @gast128 Yes, that's sort of what I want. I want a "null function" instead of a null pointer so I can call it safely no matter if it's been set or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++14 supports generic lambdas:

```
std::function<void(int foo, float bar)> somefunc  = [](auto&&...) {};
somefunc(42, 4711.0f);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define a null function:

```
struct nullfunc_t
{
    template<class F>
    operator std::function<F>()
    { return [](auto&&...){}; }
} nullfunc;
```

Now, this becomes legal and do The Right Thing(TM):

```
int main()
{
    std::function<void(int, float)> somefunc1 = nullfunc;
    std::function<void(float, int)> somefunc2 = nullfunc;
    somefunc1(1, 2.f);
    somefunc2(1.f, 2);
}
```

([demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bdaee45c100cf39))

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer from @bolov though, as it's more straight-forward (requires no additional code somewhere else).